# bash autocompletion not working for filenames (Debian wheezy 64bit)

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Bash auto completion seems to work normally except on files.

ie, if I am in / and there is some directory structure

```
/
 folder1/
  folder2/
   fileName
   nameOfFile
  other2/
 otherfolder/
```

I can type cd f(tab)f(tab) to get "cd folder1/folder2/"

but when in folder2/ typing fi(tab) does nothing.

what gives?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `cd` it only auto completes folder names since you can only `cd` to folders.

You can try with `cat ./<tab-tab>` to get your files.

Comment: everything should show up when tab completing with `ls` as well

Comment: @h3rrmiller ya pretty much any command that has auto complete operates on files should work

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem occasionally and here are my two common causes:

ID10t Error: I spell the filename incorrectly.

Not Specific Enough: I may type "file", but in that directory I have two files - file1 and file2. When using autocomplete, be as specific as possible and be aware of files that begin with the same few characters.